# How to store user_id in CakePHP (2.10) table session?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I tried to apply the solution found in this article :
https://thomasv.nl/2015/09/cakephp-2-8-x-storing-sessions-in-the-database-revisited/

But with CakePHP 2.10, it seems that the callbacks methods are not working at all on my custom session model. I'm unable to store the "user_id" in the session table.

Even afterDelete or any other callback do not work. For example, if I insert a "return false" at the end of beforeSave, it still saves in the database !

Here is the code in the custom session model :

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
        $this->data[$this->alias]['user_id'] = AuthComponent::user('id');
        return true;
}
```

Any help ?
Thank you !

Comment: There's most likely a mistake in the session configuration, and/or the model class/filename. Without seeing all the relevant code however, it's not possible to give you a specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
 public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
     $this->data[$this->alias]['user_id'] = CakeSession::read("Auth.User.id");
     return true;
 }
```

Note that this is only for CakePHP 2.x - and should be avoided. Usually you pass the session data you need into the model layer. In 3.x you cannot statically access the session anymore, therefor you definitely need to pass the data into the model layer.

Make sure you've called the controllers parent beforeFilter();

```
public function beforeFilter(){
    parent::beforeFilter();
}
```

Make sure you've added this at the top of your model file:

```
App::uses('CakeSession', 'Model/Datasource')
```